# Golang: Accessing Google App Engine CloudSQL

Tags: google-app-engine, go

New question: Everything I can find on Google suggests that the CloudSQL connector should be working, with the exception of the source code itself (and importing the SDK's cloudsql doesn't work).  Is there some place I can find this updated library, if it exists?

---EDIT: I have my answer: it seems the problem is with CloudSQL itself rather than with the driver or something similar.---

I'm trying to access CloudSQL from a Google App Engine Go program.
I've tried both go-sql-driver/mysql and ziutek/mymysql, using Go 1.2.1 and Go 1.4.2.  I've tried both the go get version of go-sql-driver and cloned it directly from Github.  I've tried both the App Engine installer and the archive.

Every time I try to access a database with my application, the resulting webpage states:
cloudsql: not supported in dev yet

I've seen the other similar question here, tried everything noted there, none of it worked.

The code in question:

```
    import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    _ "appengine/cloudsql"
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"
)

func adminLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    username := formatter(r.FormValue("username"))
    password := formatter(r.FormValue("password"))
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
        "root:password@cloudsql(ws-virtual-classroom:database)/logins") // And all the variations on that string I could think of...
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    } else {
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT username FROM admin_logins WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1", username, password)
        defer rows.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        } else {
            var user string
            for rows.Next() {
                err = rows.Scan(&user)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Print(err)
                } else {
                    makeCookie(w, r, user, true, true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    teachersHome(w, r)
}
```

The result (this is displayed in my browser after I submit the login form):

```
the runtime process gave a bad HTTP response: ''

2015/05/17 01:53:06 cloudsql: not supported in dev yet
2015/05/17 01:53:06 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:56970: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 12 [running]:
net/http.funcÂ·011()
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1130 +0xbb
database/sql.(*Rows).Close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/database/sql/sql.go:1659 +0x31
main57750.adminLogin(0x7f76a72ef5d8, 0xc208045860, 0xc2080c4820)
    main.go:208 +0x25a
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x927c78, 0x7f76a72ef5d8, 0xc208045860, 0xc2080c4820)
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1265 +0x41
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc20800c730, 0x7f76a72ef5d8, 0xc208045860, 0xc2080c4820)
    /home/daniel/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:98 +0x297
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc20803a6f0, 0x7f76a72ef5d8, 0xc208045860, 0xc2080c4820)
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1541 +0x17d
appengine_internal.handleFilteredHTTP(0x7f76a72ef5d8, 0xc208045860, 0xc2080c4820)
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/appengine_internal/api_dev.go:98 +0x413
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x927248, 0x7f76a72ef5d8, 0xc208045860, 0xc2080c4820)
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1265 +0x41
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc208042540, 0x7f76a72ef5d8, 0xc208045860, 0xc2080c4820)
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1703 +0x19a
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc2080457c0)
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1204 +0xb57
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /tmp/appengine/go_appengine/goroot/src/net/http/server.go:1751 +0x35e
```

This is when running it with goapp serve.  If I deploy it I seem to have the same problem--the resulting page is blank rather than showing that text, but the log error messages are the same.

Answer (score 6):

The updated library is here: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine. It doesn't have CloudSQL though. Perhaps you should just use a regular mysql connection locally:

```
func dialSQL() (*sql.DB, error) {
    if appengine.IsDevAppServer() {
        // or sql.Open("mysql", "user-name:password@ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance/dbname")
        return sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")
    }
    return sql.Open("mysql", "cloudsql:my-instance*dbname/user/passwd")
}
```

Using a local database is usually the best option because connecting to a live database can be super dangerous. For example it's all too easy to accidentally run your tests against your production database and drop everything.

Nevertheless, Google has instructions for connecting to CloudSQL here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction. The instructions for 3rd party tools will work for Go too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think cloudsql does anything? The source just looks like it returns that error no matter what lol

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/cloudsql/cloudsql.go

```
// Dial connects to the named Cloud SQL instance.
    func Dial(instance string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return connect(instance)
    }
```

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/cloudsql/cloudsql_dev.go

```
func connect(instance string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return nil, errors.New("cloudsql: not supported in dev yet")
}
```

Comment: Okay, yeah, it's definitely cloudsql rather than the driver or anything else.